# Keras image segmentation: loss function for a single pixel

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

My problem may be easy to solve for you but I did not found any answer out there and have no idea how to implement that as I am also fairly new to Keras and Tensorflow.

The problem: I use a pretrained image segmentation net ([PSPNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.01105) by Hengshuang Zhao et al 2017), for which someone converted the weights from Caffe to Keras with Tensorflow backend ([PSPNet-Keras-tensorflow](https://github.com/Vladkryvoruchko/PSPNet-Keras-tensorflow)).

I want to compute the gradient of a categorical crossentropy loss function with respect to the weights, not that complicated so far and solvable by me. But the problem is the loss function, because I only want the loss at a single pixel of the prediction.

What I have so far for the loss of the whole image is:

```
weights = model.trainable_weights

gradients = model.optimizer.get_gradients(model.total_loss, weights) 
# model is compiled with categorical crossentropy

input_tensor = [model.inputs[0],  # input data
                model.sample_weights[0],  # how much to weight each sample by
                model.targets[0],  # labels
                keras.backend.learning_phase()  # train or test mode]

get_gradients = keras.backend.function(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=gradients)
```

How do I have to adjust this to calculate only the loss for a single pixel?

PS: Afterwards I want to iterate over a whole image (~2million pixels) and calculate for each pixel the gradient of the categorical crossentropy loss with respect to the weights.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a model with a different loss function that is only evaluated on the particular pixel you're interested in.

EDIT:
The `model.total_loss` you're using is the overall loss. Please take a look at \keras\engine\training.py. You will find there the actual calculation of the total loss. Try to reproduce the steps, but you will still need a custom loss function that won't reduce the spatial dimensions. I hope this will be enough for you to get you started.

Comment: As I do not want to train new weights, I have to use the pretrained weights from [PSPNet-Keras-tensorflow](https://github.com/Vladkryvoruchko/PSPNet-Keras-tensorflow). How would this loss function look like? So I need a way to just look at a single pixel. I also want to iterate over an whole image (~2million pixels) and look at each pixel individually.

Comment: You can load any weights you like, regardless of the loss function you are using. **However**, if you need to do this for all the pixels, than this approach will be very inefficient.